# BigCommerce Stencil - Maximum Faceted Search Items?

Tags: bigcommerce

We are seeing an issue with the Cornerstone Light theme where the maximum number of facets available is 30 on a category page. Once the user clicks "Show More", the code only lists 30 facets. The client has over 100, so we need to have all of these available. I know Blueprint has the added functionality of the additional facets popup.

Are the additional facets not available currently in Stencil?

Does Stencil limit the facets to 30 options per type?

I would like to be 100% sure on this before I have to develop my own additional functionality to support more facets.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stencil does limit to 30 options per type, but Blueprint allows for 500. <strike>We will expand faceted search/stencil to allow for more options in the future.</strike>

Cornerstone 1.3 will offer support for this.

Comment: Ok, great. I see in the release notes, Cornerstone 1.2 was released on 5/12/16. Is there a tentative release date set for v1.3? Thanks

Comment: I don't presently have one. We've pushed 1.2.1 out and are working on 1.3.